# Integrating blinking light code and time on/off code

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, rgb-led

I'm trying to integrate code from one of my projects with another. One is code that blinks some Adafruit Neopixel LED strips at a specific rate and the other is a time on/off circuit here is the code for both of these projects, respectively:

```
NeoPixel LEDs

#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#ifdef __AVR__
#include <avr/power.h> // Required for 16 MHz Adafruit Trinket
#endif

#define PIN        6
#define NUMPIXELS 7


Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void NeoBlink(int num, int wait)
{
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
pixels.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
}
pixels.show();
delay(8000);
for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
{
pixels.setPixelColor(j, 255, 255, 255);
}
pixels.show();
delay(3);
}

void setup()
{
pixels.begin();
pixels.setBrightness(255);
}

void loop()
{
NeoBlink(7, 500);
}
```

AND

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <hd44780.h>
#include <hd44780ioClass/hd44780_I2Cexp.h>


hd44780_I2Cexp lcd;//0x3F is my lcd address, maybe not yours!
RTC_DS3231 RTC;

#define HD44780_LCDOBJECT

//-----------------------//
//------Variables--------//
//-----------------------//

//------First Timer 
byte onhour1;
byte onmin1;
byte onsec1;

byte offhour1;
byte offmin1;
byte offsec1;
//------Pages or menus
int page_counter=1;
int subpage1_counter=0;
int subpage2_counter=0;

//-------To convert clock into single number
unsigned long Time;
unsigned long Hour;
unsigned long Min;
unsigned long Sec;
//------To convert first timer into Single number
unsigned long on_Time1;
unsigned long on_hour1;
unsigned long on_min1;
unsigned long on_sec1;

unsigned long off_Time1;
unsigned long off_hour1;
unsigned long off_min1;
unsigned long off_sec1;

//-------Push buttons current/last state 
boolean current_up = LOW;          
boolean last_up=LOW;            
boolean current_sel = LOW;
boolean last_sel = LOW;
boolean last_down = LOW;
boolean current_down = LOW;
//-------Pins
int up=2;      //Up button to pin 2
int sel=3;     //Select button to pin 3
int down=4;   //Down button to pin 4

//Custom return char
byte back[8] = {
  0b00100,
  0b01000,
  0b11111,
  0b01001,
  0b00101,
  0b00001,
  0b00001,
  0b11111
};

//Custom arrow char
byte arrow[8] = {
  0b01000,
  0b00100,
  0b00010,
  0b11111,
  0b00010,
  0b00100,
  0b01000,
  0b00000
};

void setup() { 
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
     
     Wire.begin();
     RTC.begin();
     lcd.init();
     lcd.backlight();
     lcd.clear();
  lcd.createChar(1, back);//Custom chars
  lcd.createChar(2, arrow);    
//--------eePROM  read values-------//
//------First Timer 
onhour1=EEPROM.read(0);
onmin1=EEPROM.read(1);
onsec1=EEPROM.read(2);

offhour1=EEPROM.read(3);
offmin1=EEPROM.read(4);
offsec1=EEPROM.read(5);

}

   //---- De-bouncing function for all buttons----//
boolean debounce(boolean last, int pin)
{
boolean current = digitalRead(pin);
if (last != current)
{
delay(10);
current = digitalRead(pin);
}
return current;
}

void loop() {
  
current_up = debounce(last_up, up);         //Debounce for Up button
current_sel = debounce(last_sel, sel);      //Debounce for Select  button
current_down = debounce(last_down, down);   //Debounce for Down button  
  
DateTime now = RTC.now();        // Clock call
now = RTC.now();

//-----Up/Down functions to move main pages------///   
 
if(subpage1_counter==0 && subpage2_counter==0){ //up/down buttons enabled if subpages counters are 0,Disabled if 1,2..etc to work on submenus
  
//Page Up
    if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){ //Up button pressed
      lcd.clear();                            //Clear lcd if page is changed to print new one
      if(page_counter <3){                   //Page counter never higher than 3(total of pages)
      page_counter ++;                       //Page up      
      }
      else{
      page_counter= 1;                       //If higher than 3 (last page)go to main page
      }
  
} 
last_up = current_up;                   //Save up button last state 

//Page Down
    if (last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down button pressed
      lcd.clear();                               //Clear lcd if page is changed to print new one
      if(page_counter >1){                      //Page counter never lower than 1 
      page_counter --;                          //Page down
      
      }
      else{
      page_counter= 3;                 //If lower than 1(first page)go to last page
      }
  }    
    last_down = current_down;         //Save down button last state
}  
//------------Pages and submenus display and control----------//  
  switch (page_counter){
    case 1:                      //Content of main page
     last_sel=current_sel;  //Save last state of select button when we jump from the save screen
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("ULTRA MEGA TIMER");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("TIME");
      
//--------Show  Time On LCD

lcd.setCursor(7,1);                 
if(now.hour() < 10)
{
lcd.print("0");
}
lcd.print(now.hour(), DEC); //Print hour
lcd.print(':');
if(now.minute() < 10)
{
lcd.print("0");
}
lcd.print(now.minute(), DEC); //Print min
lcd.print(':');
if(now.second() < 10)
{
lcd.print("0");
}
lcd.print(now.second(), DEC); //Print sec
    //case 1
    break;

    case 2:                   //Content and functions of page 2
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("T1");
      lcd.setCursor(3,0);
      lcd.print("ON");
      lcd.setCursor(1,1);
      lcd.write(byte(1));
      lcd.setCursor(3,1);
      lcd.print("OFF");

            lcd.setCursor(7,0);    //Printing on/off values
            if(onhour1<10){
              lcd.print("0");
            }
            lcd.print(onhour1);
            lcd.setCursor(10,0);
            if(onmin1<10){
              lcd.print("0");
            }
            lcd.print(onmin1);
            lcd.setCursor(13,0);
            if(onsec1<10){
              lcd.print("0");
            }
            lcd.print(onsec1);
            lcd.setCursor(7,1);
            if(offhour1<10){
              lcd.print("0"); 
            }
            lcd.print(offhour1);
            lcd.setCursor(10,1);
            if(offmin1<10){
              lcd.print("0");
            }
            lcd.print(offmin1);
            lcd.setCursor(13,1);
            if(offsec1<10){
              lcd.print("0");
            }
            lcd.print(offsec1);
                        
//--------------Modifying on/off values-------//
     // Sub counter control
     if (last_sel== LOW && current_sel == HIGH){ //select button pressed
      if(subpage1_counter <7){                    // subpage counter never higher than 7 (total of items)
     subpage1_counter ++;                         //subcounter to move beetwen submenu
     }
     else{                                       //If subpage higher than 7 (total of items) return to first item
      subpage1_counter=1;
     }
     }
     last_sel=current_sel;                      //Save last state of select button

     //First item control(subpage_counter =1) onhour1
     if(subpage1_counter==1){
     lcd.setCursor(0,1);         //Delete last arrow position (back)
     lcd.print(" ");                                         
     lcd.setCursor(6,0);          //Place arrow in front of selected item
     lcd.write(byte(2));         
     //Move item + or -
     if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){  //Up 
      if(onhour1 < 23){
     onhour1 ++;
      }
      else{
     onhour1 =0;
      }
     }
     last_up=current_up;
     
     if(last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down
     if(onhour1 >0){
      onhour1 --; 
     }
     else{
      onhour1=23;
     }
     }
     last_down=current_down;
    }//subpage1_counter 1

     //Second item control(subpage_counter =2) onmin1
     if(subpage1_counter==2){
     lcd.setCursor(6,0);         //Delete last arrow position (onhour1)
     lcd.print(" ");                                         
     lcd.setCursor(9,0);          //Place arrow in front of selected item
     lcd.write(byte(2));         
     //Move item + or -
     if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){  //Up 
      if(onmin1 < 59){
     onmin1 ++;
      }
      else{
     onmin1 =0;
      }
     }
     last_up=current_up;
     
     if(last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down
     if(onmin1 >0){
      onmin1 --; 
     }
     else{
      onmin1=59;
     }
     }
     last_down=current_down;
    }//subpage1_counter 2
    
     //Thirth item control(subpage_counter =3) onsec1
     if(subpage1_counter==3){
     lcd.setCursor(9,0);         //Delete last arrow position (onmin1)
     lcd.print(" ");                                        
     lcd.setCursor(12,0);          //Place arrow in front of selected item
     lcd.write(byte(2));         
     //Move item + or -
     if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){  //Up 
      if(onsec1 < 59){
     onsec1 ++;
      }
      else{
     onsec1 =0;
      }
     }
     last_up=current_up;
     
     if(last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down
     if(onsec1 >0){
      onsec1 --; 
     }
     else{
      onsec1=59;
     }
     }
     last_down=current_down;
    }//subpage1_counter 3

     //fourth item control(subpage_counter =4) offhour1
     if(subpage1_counter==4){
     lcd.setCursor(12,0);         //Delete last arrow position (onsec1)
     lcd.print(" ");                                         
     lcd.setCursor(6,1);          //Place arrow in front of selected item
     lcd.write(byte(2));         
     //Move item + or -
     if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){  //Up 
      if(offhour1 < 23){
     offhour1 ++;
      }
      else{
     offhour1 =0;
      }
     }
     last_up=current_up;
     
     if(last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down
     if(offhour1 >0){
      offhour1 --; 
     }
     else{
      offhour1=23;
     }
     }
     last_down=current_down;
    }//subpage1_counter 4

     //fifth item control(subpage_counter =5) offmin1
     if(subpage1_counter==5){
     lcd.setCursor(6,1);         //Delete last arrow position (offhour1)
     lcd.print(" ");                                         
     lcd.setCursor(9,1);          //Place arrow in front of selected item
     lcd.write(byte(2));         
     //Move item + or -
     if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){  //Up 
      if(offmin1 < 59){
     offmin1 ++;
      }
      else{
     offmin1 =0;
      }
     }
     last_up=current_up;
     
     if(last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down
     if(offmin1 >0){
      offmin1 --; 
     }
     else{
      offmin1=59;
     }
     }
     last_down=current_down;
    }//subpage1_counter 5 

     //sixth item control(subpage_counter =6) offsec1
     if(subpage1_counter==6){
     lcd.setCursor(9,1);         //Delete last arrow position (offmin1)
     lcd.print(" ");                                         
     lcd.setCursor(12,1);          //Place arrow in front of selected item
     lcd.write(byte(2));         
     //Move item + or -
     if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){  //Up 
      if(offsec1 < 59){
     offsec1 ++;
      }
      else{
     offsec1 =0;
      }
     }
     last_up=current_up;
     
     if(last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down
     if(offsec1 >0){
      offsec1 --; 
     }
     else{
      offsec1=59;
     }
     }
     last_down=current_down;
    }//subpage1_counter 6 
          

     //seventh item control(subpage_counter =7) back
     if(subpage1_counter==7){
     lcd.setCursor(12,1);         //Delete last arrow position (offsec1)
     lcd.print(" ");                                         
     lcd.setCursor(0,1);          //Place arrow in front of selected item
     lcd.write(byte(2));         
     //Move item + or -
     if (last_up== LOW && current_up == HIGH){  //Up
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);         //Delete last arrow position (back) to exit
      lcd.print(" "); 
     subpage1_counter=0;         //Exit submenu. Up/down butons enabled to move main pages     
     }
     last_up=current_up;
     
     if(last_down== LOW && current_down == HIGH){//Down
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);         //Delete last arrow position (back)
      lcd.print(" "); 
     subpage1_counter=1;         //Go to first item (onhour1)
     }
     last_down=current_down;
    }//subpage1_counter 7
    //case 2
    break;

    case 3:                //Page 3 display and functions
      lcd.setCursor(4,0);
      lcd.print("PRESS SEL");
      lcd.setCursor(5,1);
      lcd.print("TO SAVE");
     if (last_sel== LOW && current_sel == HIGH){  //select button pressed.Save settings to eeprom
  EEPROM.write(0, onhour1);
  EEPROM.write(1, onmin1);
  EEPROM.write(2, onsec1);
  EEPROM.write(3, offhour1);
  EEPROM.write(4, offmin1);
  EEPROM.write(5, offsec1);
  lcd.clear();                 //Print message "SAVED!"
  lcd.setCursor(5,1);
  lcd.print("SAVED!");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();               //Clear lcd and go to main page
  page_counter=1;
     }
     last_sel=current_sel;  //Save last state of select button
      
    //Case 3
    break;
  }//switch


//-------------Conversion----------//

//---------Converting clock time into single number 
 
Hour = now.hour();
Min = now.minute();
Sec = now.second();
Time = (Hour*10000+ Min*100 +Sec*1);  

//--------Converting firt timer on/off into single number
on_hour1=onhour1;
on_min1=onmin1;
on_sec1=onsec1;
on_Time1=(on_hour1*10000 + on_min1*100 + on_sec1);

off_hour1=offhour1;
off_min1=offmin1;
off_sec1=offsec1;
off_Time1=(off_hour1*10000 + off_min1*100 + off_sec1);
   


//----Relay Function----//
if(onhour1 == offhour1 && onmin1==offmin1 && onsec1==offsec1){
   digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
}

if(on_Time1 < off_Time1){
  
             if(Time >= on_Time1 && Time < off_Time1){  //Start
             digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
             }
             else if(Time >= off_Time1) {
             digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
             }
             else{
             digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);
             }
}
if (on_Time1 > off_Time1){

            if(Time >= on_Time1 && Time <= 235959){     //Start
            digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);  
            }
            else if(Time < off_Time1 ){
            digitalWrite(Relay, HIGH);
            }
            else if(Time >= off_Time1 && Time < on_Time1){
            digitalWrite(Relay, LOW);  
            }
}


}//void loop
```

And this is my attempt at integration:

```
void loop() {

  current_up = debounce(last_up, up);         //Debounce for Up button
  current_sel = debounce(last_sel, sel);      //Debounce for Select  button
  current_down = debounce(last_down, down);   //Debounce for Down button

  DateTime now = RTC.now();        // Clock call
  now = RTC.now();

  //-----Up/Down functions to move main pages------///

  if (subpage1_counter == 0 && subpage2_counter == 0) { //up/down buttons enabled if subpages counters are 0,Disabled if 1,2..etc to work on submenus

    //Page Up
    if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up button pressed
      lcd.clear();                            //Clear lcd if page is changed to print new one
      if (page_counter < 3) {                //Page counter never higher than 3(total of pages)
        page_counter ++;                       //Page up
      }
      else {
        page_counter = 1;                      //If higher than 3 (last page)go to main page
      }

    }
    last_up = current_up;                   //Save up button last state

    //Page Down
    if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down button pressed
      lcd.clear();                               //Clear lcd if page is changed to print new one
      if (page_counter > 1) {                   //Page counter never lower than 1
        page_counter --;                          //Page down

      }
      else {
        page_counter = 3;                //If lower than 1(first page)go to last page
      }
    }
    last_down = current_down;         //Save down button last state
  }
  //------------Pages and submenus display and control----------//
  switch (page_counter) {
    case 1:                      //Content of main page
      last_sel = current_sel; //Save last state of select button when we jump from the save screen
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("ULTRA MEGA TIMER");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("TIME");

      //--------Show  Time On LCD

      lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
      if (now.hour() < 10)
      {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(now.hour(), DEC); //Print hour
      lcd.print(':');
      if (now.minute() < 10)
      {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(now.minute(), DEC); //Print min
      lcd.print(':');
      if (now.second() < 10)
      {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(now.second(), DEC); //Print sec
      //case 1
      break;

    case 2:                   //Content and functions of page 2
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("T1");
      lcd.setCursor(3, 0);
      lcd.print("ON");
      lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
      lcd.write(byte(1));
      lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
      lcd.print("OFF");

      lcd.setCursor(7, 0);   //Printing on/off values
      if (onhour1 < 10) {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(onhour1);
      lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
      if (onmin1 < 10) {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(onmin1);
      lcd.setCursor(13, 0);
      if (onsec1 < 10) {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(onsec1);
      lcd.setCursor(7, 1);
      if (offhour1 < 10) {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(offhour1);
      lcd.setCursor(10, 1);
      if (offmin1 < 10) {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(offmin1);
      lcd.setCursor(13, 1);
      if (offsec1 < 10) {
        lcd.print("0");
      }
      lcd.print(offsec1);

      //--------------Modifying on/off values-------//
      // Sub counter control
      if (last_sel == LOW && current_sel == HIGH) { //select button pressed
        if (subpage1_counter < 7) {                 // subpage counter never higher than 7 (total of items)
          subpage1_counter ++;                         //subcounter to move beetwen submenu
        }
        else {                                      //If subpage higher than 7 (total of items) return to first item
          subpage1_counter = 1;
        }
      }
      last_sel = current_sel;                    //Save last state of select button

      //First item control(subpage_counter =1) onhour1
      if (subpage1_counter == 1) {
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);        //Delete last arrow position (back)
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(6, 0);         //Place arrow in front of selected item
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        //Move item + or -
        if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up
          if (onhour1 < 23) {
            onhour1 ++;
          }
          else {
            onhour1 = 0;
          }
        }
        last_up = current_up;

        if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down
          if (onhour1 > 0) {
            onhour1 --;
          }
          else {
            onhour1 = 23;
          }
        }
        last_down = current_down;
      }//subpage1_counter 1

      //Second item control(subpage_counter =2) onmin1
      if (subpage1_counter == 2) {
        lcd.setCursor(6, 0);        //Delete last arrow position (onhour1)
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(9, 0);         //Place arrow in front of selected item
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        //Move item + or -
        if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up
          if (onmin1 < 59) {
            onmin1 ++;
          }
          else {
            onmin1 = 0;
          }
        }
        last_up = current_up;

        if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down
          if (onmin1 > 0) {
            onmin1 --;
          }
          else {
            onmin1 = 59;
          }
        }
        last_down = current_down;
      }//subpage1_counter 2

      //Thirth item control(subpage_counter =3) onsec1
      if (subpage1_counter == 3) {
        lcd.setCursor(9, 0);        //Delete last arrow position (onmin1)
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(12, 0);         //Place arrow in front of selected item
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        //Move item + or -
        if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up
          if (onsec1 < 59) {
            onsec1 ++;
          }
          else {
            onsec1 = 0;
          }
        }
        last_up = current_up;

        if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down
          if (onsec1 > 0) {
            onsec1 --;
          }
          else {
            onsec1 = 59;
          }
        }
        last_down = current_down;
      }//subpage1_counter 3

      //fourth item control(subpage_counter =4) offhour1
      if (subpage1_counter == 4) {
        lcd.setCursor(12, 0);        //Delete last arrow position (onsec1)
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(6, 1);         //Place arrow in front of selected item
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        //Move item + or -
        if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up
          if (offhour1 < 23) {
            offhour1 ++;
          }
          else {
            offhour1 = 0;
          }
        }
        last_up = current_up;

        if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down
          if (offhour1 > 0) {
            offhour1 --;
          }
          else {
            offhour1 = 23;
          }
        }
        last_down = current_down;
      }//subpage1_counter 4

      //fifth item control(subpage_counter =5) offmin1
      if (subpage1_counter == 5) {
        lcd.setCursor(6, 1);        //Delete last arrow position (offhour1)
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(9, 1);         //Place arrow in front of selected item
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        //Move item + or -
        if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up
          if (offmin1 < 59) {
            offmin1 ++;
          }
          else {
            offmin1 = 0;
          }
        }
        last_up = current_up;

        if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down
          if (offmin1 > 0) {
            offmin1 --;
          }
          else {
            offmin1 = 59;
          }
        }
        last_down = current_down;
      }//subpage1_counter 5

      //sixth item control(subpage_counter =6) offsec1
      if (subpage1_counter == 6) {
        lcd.setCursor(9, 1);        //Delete last arrow position (offmin1)
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(12, 1);         //Place arrow in front of selected item
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        //Move item + or -
        if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up
          if (offsec1 < 59) {
            offsec1 ++;
          }
          else {
            offsec1 = 0;
          }
        }
        last_up = current_up;

        if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down
          if (offsec1 > 0) {
            offsec1 --;
          }
          else {
            offsec1 = 59;
          }
        }
        last_down = current_down;
      }//subpage1_counter 6


      //seventh item control(subpage_counter =7) back
      if (subpage1_counter == 7) {
        lcd.setCursor(12, 1);        //Delete last arrow position (offsec1)
        lcd.print(" ");
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);         //Place arrow in front of selected item
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        //Move item + or -
        if (last_up == LOW && current_up == HIGH) { //Up
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);        //Delete last arrow position (back) to exit
          lcd.print(" ");
          subpage1_counter = 0;       //Exit submenu. Up/down butons enabled to move main pages
        }
        last_up = current_up;

        if (last_down == LOW && current_down == HIGH) { //Down
          lcd.setCursor(0, 1);        //Delete last arrow position (back)
          lcd.print(" ");
          subpage1_counter = 1;       //Go to first item (onhour1)
        }
        last_down = current_down;
      }//subpage1_counter 7
      //case 2
      break;

    case 3:                //Page 3 display and functions
      lcd.setCursor(4, 0);
      lcd.print("PRESS SEL");
      lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
      lcd.print("TO SAVE");
      if (last_sel == LOW && current_sel == HIGH) { //select button pressed.Save settings to eeprom
        EEPROM.write(0, onhour1);
        EEPROM.write(1, onmin1);
        EEPROM.write(2, onsec1);
        EEPROM.write(3, offhour1);
        EEPROM.write(4, offmin1);
        EEPROM.write(5, offsec1);
        lcd.clear();                 //Print message "SAVED!"
        lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
        lcd.print("SAVED!");
        delay(2000);
        lcd.clear();               //Clear lcd and go to main page
        page_counter = 1;
      }
      last_sel = current_sel; //Save last state of select button

      //Case 3
      break;
  }//switch


  //-------------Conversion----------//

  //---------Converting clock time into single number

  Hour = now.hour();
  Min = now.minute();
  Sec = now.second();
  Time = (Hour * 10000 + Min * 100 + Sec * 1);

  //--------Converting firt timer on/off into single number
  on_hour1 = onhour1;
  on_min1 = onmin1;
  on_sec1 = onsec1;
  on_Time1 = (on_hour1 * 10000 + on_min1 * 100 + on_sec1);

  off_hour1 = offhour1;
  off_min1 = offmin1;
  off_sec1 = offsec1;
  off_Time1 = (off_hour1 * 10000 + off_min1 * 100 + off_sec1);



 //----Relay Function----//
if(onhour1 == offhour1 && onmin1==offmin1 && onsec1==offsec1){
   NeoBlink(0, 0);
}

if(on_Time1 < off_Time1){
  
             if(Time >= on_Time1 && Time < off_Time1){  //Start
             NeoBlink(7, 500);
             }
             else if(Time >= off_Time1) {
             NeoBlink(0, 0);
             }
             else{
            NeoBlink(0, 0);
             }
}
if (on_Time1 > off_Time1){

            if(Time >= on_Time1 && Time <= 235959){     //Start
            NeoBlink(7, 500);  
            }
            else if(Time < off_Time1 ){
            NeoBlink(7, 500);
            }
            else if(Time >= off_Time1 && Time < on_Time1){
            NeoBlink(0, 0);  
            }
}


}//void
```

(I had to cut this last one down a bit^ -too many characters, the most important stuff is there though)

This actually has no apparent errors BUT when I run it-it messes with my RTC, LCD and I cannot access the serial display (referring to a Time On/Off Circuit minus the 5v relay I made [image: Schematic]

Also the lights don't run like they do when I run the first string of code I posted.
The majority of the changes are at the end where I subbed in NeoBlink() for digitalwrite(). I also made the correct changes to voidsetup() and voidloop().
Of course I can think of some reasons why this code wouldn't run but I have a specific question.

My question is would it even be possible to integrate the first string of code into the second or will it have to be completely re-formatted for integration? If re-formatting is required-where should I start?

Thanks

Comment: try merging the code before posting ... that way you can ask an actual question about a problem you are having

Comment: You're right-I've actually already tried. I don't know why I didn't do that.